# Sending command to server from session opened via MSTSC (Remote Desktop Connection)

Tags: c#, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-execution

We are looking for ways to send command (we are trying to open browser via command) from Session connected. To elaborate more

Server A opens remote connection to Client B via (mstsc). On Client B user clicks on shortcut and we need to execute command which allows us to open browser in Server A. Is it possible? If yes if you can please give head start it would be great. We are using Windows environment. If we can use C# to achieve same would be great.

Comment: Not really possible using standard tools, via the remote connection. Possibly you could just detect which PC opened the connection and open another remote PS-Exec session in reverse, but you would probably need to be on the same network and be domain admin. I don't get it, why can user not click directly on a shortcut on Server A anyway?

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface for your kind input ! Unfortunately user has very limited rights on Server A so can't open it directly also when they login on Client B a token is generated which needed to be passed along with when we send command to Server A. We have inherited legacy application and existing tool which supports same framework (It's blackbox to us) no longer can be used due to OS limitations.

Comment: Bit hacky, but perhaps instead of the RD shortcut: a batch script that opens the RD, and waits for the user to copy in the token, then opens the browser.